# How to change text of sticky element depending on scrolling through several section?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-animations

I have been trying the sticky scroll animation where the text remains fixed at its position and changes according to scroll. Images are placed according to scroll but this is not changing.

```
<div class="sticky-text">
        <div class="sticky-text2">
            Yes!!
        </div>
        <div class="sticky-text3">
            No!!
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here `sticky-text` is fixed container and i want `sticky-text2` and `sticky-text3` to change with animations according to scroll.

JS

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= offset) {
    $(".sticky-text2").addClass("active");
} else {
   $(".stick-text2").removeClass("active");
}
```

});

i have tried this but not sure about it as i am a JS beginner. I need this project for my it-fest , please help me out.

Here is website from which i was inspired to use this element. (the fixed text and image moving section) [enter link description here](https://riveal.fr)

Thank you in advance!
Hoping for a positive response.
v